# Spring security LDAP- Error LDAP: error code 50 - Insufficient Access Rights

Tags: ldap, openldap, spring-ldap, ldap-query, spring-security-ldap

I am trying to use LDAP authentication with spring sceurity. I followed the article https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ for implementation. I am getting error "[LDAP: error code 50 - Insufficient Access Rights]; nested exception is javax.naming.NoPermissionException: [LDAP: error code 50 - Insufficient Access Rights]; remaining name 'uid=pmerla,ou=people'". How can this issue be fixed? below is my code for configuration

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource()
            .url("ldaps://ldap.uchicago.edu/dc=uchicago,dc=edu")
            .and()
            .passwordCompare()
            .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
            .passwordAttribute("userPassword");

}
```

}

I also tested if ldap connection is active from my terminal using below command
ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.uchicago.edu -D "uid=pmerla,ou=people,dc=uchicago,dc=edu" -W
and it is giving me correct response

```html
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#
# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object
```

How can I get my spring security ldap working? I also checked other stack overflow questions similar to this issue but nothing resolved my issue.Hence posting a new thread.Can someone please help me resolve this issue

Comment: Best practice for LDAP authentication is LDAP BIND request and not password retrieval and comparison on the client side. LDAP BIND makes the LDAP server compare the password. As you seem  to use an anonymous search, I would not expect the 'userpassword' attribute to be readable.

Comment: I already had the bind param userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people"). is this not correct?Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: These are the details which I have:
Port: 389 if using StartTLS, 636 with SSL
Base DN: dc=uchicago,dc=edu
Scope: subtree
Filter: (&(uid=<username>)(objectclass=inetOrgPerson))
Template: uid=<username>,ou=people,dc=uchicago,dc=edu

Comment: `useDnPatterns` is actually not LDAP best practice either. LDAP best pratice is to search for the DN and not to specify it beforehand as the Directory Information Tree (DIT) may not be that flat. I guess I should file a bug on Spring Security docs. This setting is not related to authenticating the LDAP client with the LDAP server. If you remove the `passwordEncoder` a `BindAuthenticator` will be used. In the `contextSource` you need to specify the credentials of the technical account used to talk to the LDAP server